# Python Igraph Infomap node labels on graph

Tags: python, igraph

I have graph showed on first image, and I used infomap from igraph to make another, but on it I dont have node labels and that is so important fo me. How to add them, I tried everything but no node labels. It is strange that prints name of nodes like this,but no labels on graph:

IGRAPH U--- 86 41 --
+ edges:
0--57 65--67 2--66 2--67 2--23 66--67 57--68 68--81 6--66 33--74 74--84 37--74
32--76 57--81 32--84 37--84 70--84 32--85 58--85 22--24 22--23 23--31 24--25
24--31 30--31 32--33 32--57 42--48 42--46 42--55 43--48 43--55 43--47 44--49
46--48 46--55 47--54 47--55 49--51 54--55 57--58
 Also,how to save that community graph to png or similar?

Code:
[image: graph one]
[image: community_graph]

```
def nlargest_indices_orig(full, n):
    full = full.copy()
    x = np.zeros(n)
    y = np.zeros(n)

    for idx in range(n):
        x[idx] = np.unravel_index(full.argmax(), full.shape)[0]
        y[idx] = np.unravel_index(full.argmax(), full.shape)[1]
        full[full == full.max()] = 0.

    return x, y

labels=range(90)
o1 = scipy.io.loadmat('out.mat')
X=(o1['out'])

K=np.zeros((90,90))
m, n = np.shape(X)
print(m)
print(n)
G = nx.Graph()
#X[np.where(X<0.5)]=0
for i in range(90):
    for j in range(90):
        if X[i,j]>0:
            s=labels[i]
            b=labels[j]
            w=X[i,j]
            G.add_edge(s,b,weight=w)
B=G.edges()
print(len(B))
ND=len(B)
print('Grana ukupno')
print(ND)
procenat=round(0.1*ND)
print('procenat')
print(procenat)
x,y=nlargest_indices_orig(X, procenat)
s1=x
s2=y

for i in s1:
    K[s1[i],s2[i]]=X[s1[i],s2[i]]
np.fill_diagonal(K, 0)
print('K')
print(K)
F = nx.Graph()

for i in range(90):
    for j in range(90):
        if K[i,j]>0:
            s=labels[i]
            b=labels[j]
            w=X[i,j]
            F.add_edge(s,b,weight=w)
edgewidth=[]
edgelabels={}
pos = nx.spring_layout(F) # position the nodes by force layout
plt.figure()
plt.axis('off')
print('Weighted graph')
for (u,v,d) in F.edges(data=True):
    print(u,v,d)
    edgewidth.append(d['weight'])
    edgelabels[(u,v)] = d['weight']
nx.draw_networkx_edges(F,pos,width=edgewidth,edge_color='r')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(F,pos, alpha=0.8, node_size=400,node_color='w',scale=100)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(F,pos, font_size=12)
pylab.savefig('Graf-s-10%.png')
plt.show()
A = F.edges()
E = ig.Graph(A)
print('E')
print(E)
community = E.community_infomap()
ig.plot( community,names=edgelabels)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two options to show labels on an igraph plot: either pass `vertex_label` parameter to `igraph.plot()`, or set the `label` vertex attribute, and igraph will use that automatically at plotting. To save the figure, simply call the `save()` method of the plot object. The format will be set automatically by the extension.

```
import igraph
g = igraph.Graph.Barabasi(n = 8, m = 2)

labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']

p = igraph.plot(g,
                vertex_label = labels,
                vertex_size = 32,
                vertex_frame_width = 0.0,
                vertex_color = '#AAAAFF')

p.save('plot1.png')
```

[image: igraph plot with labels]

Or creating the `label` vertex attribute:

```
g.vs['label'] = labels
igraph.plot(g)
```

Or if you want the indices to be used as labels:

```
igraph.plot(g, vertex_label = range(g.vcount()))
```